# Entry Color Changes To Purple When Run Xamarin Forms App On IOS Device

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

i am making an app in xamarin forms which run both on android and ios. The app runs on Android perfect but when i run my app in ios device it changes the background color of my entry or input fields to purple shown in this pic here [Iphone image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEt86.jpg) but on android this wont happen here is the android pic [Android image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ud05K.jpg) you can check these two images and compare them on android the input fields are very good with white background but on ios their background color changes to purple and also their height compresses like they are not looking like the same as they are on android also below is my xaml code for these input fields  here is the xaml code the same code for all entries also this is my custom renderer

```
<controls:XEntry 
                    x:Name="SchoolName"
                    FontSize="14"
                    WidthRequest="320"
                    HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                    VerticalOptions="Center"    
                    HasRoundedCorner="True"
                    Placeholder="e.g. School System..."
                    PlaceholderColor="#A7A7A7"
                    TextColor="Black"
                    BackgroundColor="White"    
                    IsEnabled="True"
                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Start">
                        <!--Clicked="OnActionSheetSimpleClicked"-->
                    </controls:XEntry>


using Android.Views;
using CustomRenderer.iOS;
using MathRandomizer;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(XEntry), typeof(CustomEntryRenderer))]
namespace CustomRenderer.iOS
{
public class CustomEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
{
    protected override void 
OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control != null)
        {
            // do whatever you want to the UITextField here!
            Control.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGB(255, 255, 255);
            Control.BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.Line;
        }
        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            var customControl = (XEntry)e.NewElement;
            if (customControl.HasRoundedCorner)
                Control.Layer.CornerRadius = 5;
            else
                Control.Layer.CornerRadius = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you add all relevant codes about this entry? What is XEntry? How did you implement your custom render? Add these codes so that we can test for you.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT check my question again i have added my custom entry renderer code

Comment: Ok, could you please add the code of `XEntry` also?

Comment: we have fix this issue thanks for your interest..:) (Y)